# Propagating symbology changes made with PyQGIS to Layer Styling Panel

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, rule-based

I am using a script to change the opacity on a rule-based symbology.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
opacity = 0.2

if layer.renderer().type() ==  'RuleRenderer': 
    renderer = layer.renderer()     #QgsRuleBasedRenderer 
    rule = renderer.rootRule() # QgsRuleBasedRenderer.Rule
    chil = rule.children()
    for i in range(len(chil)):        
        chil [chil.index(chil[i])].symbol().setOpacity(opacity)
        # apply the renderer to the layer
        layer.setRenderer(renderer)

##Refresh
layer.triggerRepaint()
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

The script works fine and I can see the new symbol with the correct opacity both in the canvas and in the TOC but not in the layer styling panel. Here the symbology remains unmodified and when I click on one of the rules to edit it, the opacity is still at the old value.  Also, when closing the edit rule panel, the old opacity comes back on TOC and Canvas.

Any suggestion on how to make the changes permanent?

Comment: Yes, it was my error during the copy of the code. I will correct the question. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice question!

At the end of your script you need to add:

```
layer.emitStyleChanged()
```

which will notify the "Layer Styling" panel about any changes you've made to the layer style.

Comment: Of course! Excellent solution. I was looking for a similar trigger but I couldn't figure it out. Still a lot to learn. Much appreciated.